# Python: a pattern of two signs (* and $) that creates a pyramid

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

I want to create a pattern that looks like this:

```
*
* $
* $ *
* $ * $
* $ * $ *
* $ * $
* $ *
* $
*
```

I know how to use nested loops to print pattern like this with one sign but I have difficulties to create it wth two signs.
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: try to use if condition on odd position on inner for loop to change your symbol to $

Comment: Can you add the code you have that prints just one sign? Someone can review that code and suggest a code change.

Answer (score 0):

I am using python3 here

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print('*' if j%2==0 else '$' , end=" ")
    print()
    
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4-i):
        print('*' if j%2==0 else '$' , end=" ")
    print()
```